# Credo output format

Tags: junit, elixir, circleci, circleci-2.0

I am automating the process to test my code and am using credo to test the format of my elixir code. I want to output the results and because I am using CircleCI I need the results to be in Cucumber JSON or JUnit XML. How do I configure credo to output one of these, I am currently using:

```
mix credo --all --format=json > credo-output.json
```

which as expected will give me normal json. Is it possible to either configure credo to output what I want or to convert the json to another format?

Thanks

Comment: “Is it possible to either configure credo to output what I want or to convert the json to another format?”—It’s not possible to configure `credo` to output anything else, but it’s surely possible to convert JSON to anything you want. Just write the converter and you are all set.